# how to autofill file field form in webbrowser using C#

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, webbrowser-control, autofill

I know how to auto fill text field in html but i want to know how can i fill image or file field in html ?

```
HTMLInputElement Name= (HTMLInputElement)item("name", 0);
Name.value = "my Name";
HTMLInputElement submit = (HTMLInputElement)item("SubmitButton", 0);
submit.click();
```

but how for file field ?